# Rails convention for DRYing up new/edit given high degree of sharing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

There are often lots of similarities between `new` and `edit` and (also `create` and `update`). I find that historically, what that leads me to create is a singular view that is titled `new_or_edit` where I use various permission identifiers to change the information presented. For a simple contrived example...

```
def new
  @permission = "new"
  render 'new_or_edit'
end

def edit
  @permission = "edit"
  render 'new_or_edit'
end

# new_or_edit.html.erb
<% form_for ... %>
  <% if @permission == "new" %>
    <input id="name" />
  <% else %>
    <input id="email" />
  <% end %>
  <input id="story" />
<% end %>
```

What is more "Railsy" from a convention perspective? The way I've done it above. Or to have a separate `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` and pull in partials, so a re-write would be below:

```
def new
  @permission = "new"
end

def edit
  @permission = "edit"
end

# new.html.erb
<% form_for ... %>
  <%= render @permission %>
  <%= render "generic" %>
<% end %>

# edit.html.erb
<% form_for ... %>
  <%= render @permission %>
  <%= render "generic" %>
<% end %>

# _new.html.erb
<input id="name" />

# _edit.html.erb
<input id="email" />

# _generic.html.erb
<input id="story" />
```

Personally, I've always felt my way, if designed to be readable, is nicer because ...

1. Fewer files (which is something I personally dislike with Rails development)
2. It's nice to not duplicate classes (e.g., on `form_for`) and inevitably, text, like intro text between files

That said, I'm asking now because I'm doing a refactoring anyway, and would rather not other Rails developers who look at this/ help me with it become immediately allergic to what I've written. FWIW, in my style, I also will combine the create/update methods similarly. I realize this breaks CRUD, but I do feel like it's just easier when there's SO much that's shared (realize the degree of sharing depends on project, in my case, it's a VERY high degree of sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `new_or_edit`, why not just pick one and have the other delegate to it? That's less verbose. In practice you'll usually split things up differently where `new` and `edit` are simply decoration around the same form.

For example `new`:

```
<% form_for ... do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', object: form %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

Where you'd adjust labels, where any "cancel" link went to and such on a case-by-case basis and the bulk of the form content is in the `_form` partial.

It may seem like a giant hassle to have so many files, but a reasonable number of small, simple, largely single-purpose files is often easier to keep track of than a few that are complex because they're so multi-purpose.